# I'm giving 'int' to append but again throwing ERROR

Tags: python

```
def find_gpa(sem=1):
    sub = int(input("Enter the no of subjects: "))
    credits = []
    grade = []
    temp = []
    for i in range(0,sub):
      a=i+1
      x = int(input("Enter the credits for subject {}".format(a)))
      credits.append(x)
      grade = input("Enter the Grade for subject {}".format(a))
      y = gpa_convert(grade)
      print(type(y))
      grade.append(y)
      temp.append(x*y)
    gpa = sum(temp)/sum(credits)
    tup = (gpa,sum(credits))
    print ("The Gpa of semester {} is: {}".format(sem,gpa))
    return tup

def gpa_convert(z):
    if z.lower() == 'o':
      return 10
    elif z.lower() == 'a+':
      return 9
    elif z.lower() == 'a':
      return 8
    elif z.lower() == 'b+':
      return 7
    elif z.lower() == 'b':
      return 6
    else :
      return 0
```

AttributeError：

> 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

I'm trying to append an integer in `grade` but its showing string

can you help me in rectifying the error?

Comment: `grade` is `str` returned from `input()`. Then you you try to append `y` to it and you get `AttributeError`

Comment: You have `grade` as a list but then make it a string via `input`. Did you mean to initialize a variable called `grades` as a list and then append to it?

Comment: And please, always show full traceback you get.

Comment: Improve readability

Answer (score 0):

You start with
`grade = []`

but in your loop you have :
`grade = input("Enter the Grade for subject {}".format(a))`

your list doesn't exist anymore, `grade` is now an `int`

`int` don't have append method, so this doesn't work :
`grade.append(y)`

Solution :
replace `grade = []` by `grades = []` and then use plural where a list is expected

```
def find_gpa(sem=1):
    sub = int(input("Enter the no of subjects: "))
    credits = []
    grades = []
    temp = []
    for i in range(0,sub):
      a=i+1
      x = int(input("Enter the credits for subject {}".format(a)))
      credits.append(x)
      grade = input("Enter the Grade for subject {}".format(a))
      y = gpa_convert(grade)
      print(type(y))
      grades.append(y)
      temp.append(x*y)
    gpa = sum(temp)/sum(credits)
    tup = (gpa,sum(credits))
    print ("The Gpa of semester {} is: {}".format(sem,gpa))
    return tup
```

Please note however that you declare a list in the scope of the function, but never use it or return it ! This code can be simplified a lot